# The OLE DB provider "ADSDSOObject" has not been registered - in Azure SQL Managed Instance

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, oledb

I am using Azure SQL MI. I need to connect to an active directory and get some details. to do this matter I am using link server and Open query.

When I am running my query, I get the following error:

> The OLE DB provider "ADSDSOObject" has not been registered.

When I checked the Link server Provider, I noticed "AllowInProcess" for "ADSDSOObject" is not enabled.

[Image - ADSDSOObject settings on Azure SQL MI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbfNO.jpg)

Then I execute this code successfully:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'ADsDSOObject', N'AllowInProcess', 1
```

However, it is not working and the value of the "AllowInProcess" for "ADSDSOObject" will turn to 0 again.

[Image - I cannot configure ADSDSOObject on Azure SQL MI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUBBL.jpg)

I do not know why this is happening.

Does Azure SQL MI support ADSDSOObject?

If ADSDSOObject is supported in Azure SQL Managed Instance, how to configure "ADSDSOObject"?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are only a limited number of linked server targets that are supported in Azure SQL Managed Instance like SQL Managed Instance, SQL Database, etc.

You can check this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/transact-sql-tsql-differences-sql-server#linked-servers) for Linked servers targets list and operations supported in Azure SQL Managed Instance.

Currently, Azure SQL Managed Instance does not Support Active directory yet.